# How to handle com.google.api.client.http.apache.v2.ApacheHttpTransport usage in Spring Boot 3/java 17?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-5.x, spring-boot-3

I am working on migrating a Spring Boot Application from Spring Boot 2.x/Java 11 to Spring Boot 3.x/Java 17.
In one of the classes I have the following code:

```
var httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport(httpClient);
```

where HttpClient is

```
org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient
```

instance, as Spring Boot 3.x supports JakartaEE 9 and 10.But the constructor of the

```
com.google.api.client.http.apache.v2.ApacheHttpTransport
```

is expecting instance of

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
```

So I am wondering how to handle this issue, as I do not find this google library implemented with org.apache.hc.client5.http classes?